# How can you listen to user's email being verified?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

When a user signs up they are forced to verify their email. This works but I want the user to be automatically led to the next page if they successfully verify their email. I implemented a StreamBuilder with the userChanges() function.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return StreamBuilder<User?>(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot){
      if(snapshot.data == null){
        return const SignupPage();
      }else
        
      if(snapshot.data!.emailVerified){
        return const HomePage();
      }

      return const WaitingText();
    },
  );
}
```

Now when the user verifies their mail the page doesn't get updated, but when I force a reload with currenUser.reload() it works.
Is a StreamBuilder the way to go here? I don't want to constantly reload my user until they verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the expected behavior: the `userChanges()` stream fires an event when any property of the user changes, but there is no immediate propagation of the server-side change to the client.

This means the verification is only picked up in your client when you re-authenticate the user (i.e. sign-out and sign in again) or when you force the SDK to reload the user profile.

Comment: Yes I figured. For now I use a button the user has to press to reload after verifying their email, but I would still like the page to automatically detect when the user verification state changes.